# How to add and read a List from Wildfly (v17) server

Tags: jakarta-ee, filter, jax-rs, wildfly

I have a multiple (10+) modules that I want to add support for CORS. I want to allow (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) just our organizations prod, test, development, 127.0.0.1 and localhost.

I've created a jax rs ContainerResponseFilter class looks like this:

```
@Provider
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        String origin = requestContext.getHeaderString("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");

        if(!getAllowedOriginList().contains(origin))
            throw new ForbiddenException("Not allowed.");

        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }

    private List<String> getAllowedOriginList() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "http://localhost:8080",
                "127.0.0.1:8080",
                "111.123.123.22:8080",
                "222.123.123.22:8080",
                "333.123.123.22:8080"
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you have a lots of modules with this code and you need to update an IP address, then you have to go in & update this filters in every module. That's not a good option for me. I was wondering how can I add this ip address list into Wildfly 17 server and fetch it from every module? What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You can add the list in WildFly's JNDI context.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos do you have an example about how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use WildFly's JNDI. Assuming standalone operation (domain is similar though), edit the naming section of standalone.xml to add a simple binding:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
    <bindings>
        <simple name="java:global/corsAllowedOriginList" type="java.lang.String"
            value="localhost:8080,127.0.0.1:8080,111.123.123.22:8080,222.123.123.22:8080,333.123.123.22:8080" />
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

This can be read *programmatically* using the following code:

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
String corsAllowedOriginList = ic.lookup("java:global/corsAllowedOriginList");
// can be converted to array using String.split(",")
```

It is simpler to inject it as a resource:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/corsAllowedOriginList")
private String corsOriginList;
```

I'd suggest you read this value only once at each application's initialization time and cache it.

By the way this is described in WildFly's Admin Guide in the "Naming Subsystem Configuration" section, currently [here](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Admin_Guide.html#Naming).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I use `@Resource(lookup = "java:global/corsAllowedOriginList")
    private String corsOriginList;` inside my CorsFilter class to fetch values?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, and it is a much better option (adding it to the answer).

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure if `@Resource` annotation would work in a class which is annotated with `@Provider` only.